# PHP Include based on REQUEST_URI

Tags: php, security

Is there any security risks involved in using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to include a file?  Can you pass `../../..` through the request uri somehow?

What I'm thinking is something like this:

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$path = preg_replace('~\\.html?$~', '.php', $path);
include $path;
?>
```

This should substitute ".htm" or ".html" URIs for ".php" paths and render them.  But I am concerned about security here.

Comment: How would the requested URI would look like and how do you map the requested path to your PHP file?

Comment: you can pass whatever you want in the request_uri, including html/javascript. it's up to YOU and YOUR code to make sure the value is used securely. You should **NEVER EVER** allow a user to specify a path that'll be used in include/require, no matter how good you think your security is. as it stands right now, they hit `http://yoursite.com/http://malicioussite.com/remote_takeover.php`, which outputs php code in text format, and your server is utterly and completely subverted.

Comment: Your code does not look like you are specifically concerned about security with it. It is a very fine example to allow users inject data. Filter against a whitelist at least, and find more counter-measures that invalid paths can not be injected. And yes, you can pass dots through the request URI. That is a standard variable that just gets set or unset.

Comment: @MarcB In that case `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` would be `/http://malicioussite.com/remote_takeover.php`.

Comment: Every test I've tried with paths like `../../file.php` return a `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` of just `/file.php`.  This may just be how Apache/PHP work.  Does anyone actually have any genuinely dangerous path?  As @Gumbo says, the "malicious site" path has a slash in front and would not create a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains the requested URI path and query string as it appeared in the [HTTP request line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5.1). So when `http://example.com/foo/bar?baz=quux` is requested and the server passes the request to the script file `/request_handler.php`, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` would still be `/foo/bar?baz=quux`. I’ve used mod_rewrite to map any request to `request_handler.php` as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /request_handler.php
```

So for correctness, before using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in a file system path, you would need to get rid of the query string. You can use `parse_url` to do so:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
```

But as this value comes directly from the HTTP request line without prior path resolution, it may still contain symbolic path segments like `..`.

However, path traversal is not even necessary as the requested URI path is already an absolute path reference and requesting `http://example.com/etc/passwd` should result in the inclusion of `/etc/passwd`.

So this is actually a [local file inclusion vulnerability](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/98.html).

Now to fix this, requiring a certain root directory using the [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16126328/53114) that you, chowey, have presented is a good improvement. But you would actually need to prefix it with `$basedir`:

```
$path = realpath($basedir . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH']);
if ($path && strpos($path, $basedir) === 0) {
    include $path;
}
```

This solution provides several promises:

- `$path` is either a valid, resolved path to an existing file, or `false`;
- inclusion of that file does only happen if `$basedir` is a prefix path of `$path`.

However, this may still allow access to files which are protected using some other kind of [access control like the one provided by Apache’s mod_authz_host module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html).

Answer (score 0):

**This does not actually answer the question...**

Note that you can ensure the request uri points to an actual valid filepath in the current working directory.  You can use the `realpath` function to normalize the path.

The following code would do the trick:

```
<?php
$basedir = getcwd();

$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$path = preg_replace('~\\.html?$~', '.php', $path);
$path = realpath($path);

if ($path && strpos($path, $basedir) === 0) {
    include $path;
} else {
    return false;
}
?>
```

Here I used `strpos` to verify that the `$path` starts with `$basepath`.  Since `realpath` will have removed any `../../..` funny business, this should safely keep you within the `$basepath` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed dont trust the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] before checking the basepath.

And dont make a filter that removes ../ from the path attackers can craft a nieuw way to inject if they understand the filter proces.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and chose to do the following basing myself on **Gumbo's answer** :

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);

$path = realpath(FOLDER_ROOT . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH']);

$directory_white_list_array = array('/safe_folder1', '/safe_folder1/safe_folder2');

if ($path && strpos($path, FOLDER_ROOT) === 0 && (in_array(dirname($path), $directory_white_list_array)  && ('php' == pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)))) {
    include $path;
}else{
    require_once FOLDER_ROOT."/miscellaneous_functions/navigation_error.php";
    navigation_error('1');
}
```

Summary:
Added directory whitelist and .php extension restriction.