# Server Request URI alternative implementation for redirects

Tags: php, security, redirect

We all know that '$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']' Isn't secure for redirection as it is susceptible to many forms of attacks.
A few solutions and explanations were presented to solve this:

> [PHP Include based on REQUEST_URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124970/php-include-based-on-request-uri)
>
> [any security concerns with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and header('location: ...');](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214713/any-security-concerns-with-serverrequest-uri-and-headerlocation)

I have come up with an alternative approach which I humbly request you to critique and see if it is indeed a good alternative or if it is still susceptible to something which I have not envisioned, keep in mind that I came up with this solution with the priority of security and maintainability.

I am not sure how this idea compares with other solutions like white listing directories instead of links, or parsing the incoming link to clean it of any malicious paths at the end but if you find one to be better or superior to this I welcome the explanation as to why :)

**Idea:**

White list viable redirect URL's and have each page call the link which it would like to redirect to.

**Code:**

ValidRedirectLinks.php

```
<?php
$redirect_home="/home.php";
$redirect_somePage="/somePage.php";
?>
```

redirection.php

```
<?php
function redirectTo($link){
/* pseudo code check if user is not logged in*/
if (!userLoggedIn()){
   $_SESSION['redirect']=$link;
   header("location:../login.php");
   /* I don't know if you need an exit here or not to prevent page content
    * being loaded. I think the header redirect prevents that though 
    * correct me if I am wrong */
}
```

somePage.php

```
<?php require_once('ValidRedirectLinks.php');
require_once('redirection.php');
redirectTo($redirect_somePage);
?>
//page content
```

Comment: Why do you store the redirect URL in the session? That seems like an odd place to put it.

Comment: You should store the valid links in an array, that way it is a lot easier to check.

Comment: @Halcyon, I added the redirect URL in the session so that I can pick it up within my login.php file. I don't think POST/GET methods work with Header redirects and since we can only have one redirection at any given point in time, it seemed logical to use the session as the redirect variable location.

As additional information to you, I have my login.php file default to the main page after logging in if no redirect URL is present in the session, in case the session is deleted.

Comment: @jeroen, Are you suggesting I store all the links in an array and instead of calling the function with the saved variable I call it with an index to which link I want to use in the array ?

for example:    
**ValidRedirectLinks.php**
`<?php
$Array = array('somePage' => '/somePage.php');
?>`  

**somePage.php**

`<?php require_once('ValidRedirectLinks.php');
require_once('redirection.php');
redirectTo($Array['somePage']);
?>`
//page content


If I do that, what is the advantage from just storing all the links in separate variables ? Is there a performance increase using the array ?

Comment: If you have everything in an array you can validate a given link simply by using `in_array()` so you can take the appropriate action if a user requests a non-valid url.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your comments by the way, it is greatly appreciate. One thing to note though, won't the in_array() function be potentially slower than a direct reference to which link to use ? I know that the speed comparison of execution between the two will be minute if not negligible but an increase in the number of items in the array will add onto the in_array() execution time.